# Getting no method error on attr_accessor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attr

Model.rb

```
class BaseTable < ApplicationRecord
before_save :ConverterArray
serialize :conF_string
attr_accessor :valv

def initialize(valv)
    @valv = valv
end
#  def self.Conf_count  # self. is used when u have to call the method on te whole class example User.Conf_count
#      Confirmer.count
#  end

def ConverterArray  # self. is not used when u have to call the method on the instance variable for example user = User.new, user.ConverterArray
    count = Confirmer.count
    index = Array.new(count, 0)
    conf = conF_string.map(&:to_i)
    conf.each do |n|
        index[n] = 1
    end
    index = index*""
    self.conF_string = index
end

def DecoderArray
    count = Confirmer.count
    value = []
    conf = conF_string.split("")
    i = 0
    conf.each_with_index do |n,index|
        if n=="1"
            value[i] = index
            i+=1
        end
    end
    @valv = value
end
end
```

Trying to fetch the value array by using the object.DecoderArray.valv in rails console but getting the no method error. Am i using the attr_accessor incorrectly.

Comment: Assuming your `object` in your question is an instance of `BaseTable` ... surely you should just be calling `object.valv`? Also, your method names should start with a lowercase character. Class names are capitalised. Finally, with the way you're implemented `DecoderArray`, it already returns `@valv` for you

Comment: Oh man, i just had to restart console... i don't know why it wasn't working. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you edit a file and you have the `rails console` opened, you need to restart to apply the changes to the console. To restart, you can use the method [`Rails::ConsoleMethods#reload!`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/ConsoleMethods.html#method-i-reload-21).

You can do it simply running `reload!` in `rails console`.

Comment: Thanks a ton @vnbrs